# How to access map values on the basis of keys in struts 1.x tags, not just iterate

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts

I have a getter method in the bean associated with my form, which returns a Map. I want to access the object corresponding to a given String key from the map using Struts 1.x tags. I can iterate over the map by using its entry set and retrieve each key and its corresponding value, but I can't think of a way to access the value using directly its key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
${bean.map.key}
```

to get it. Or, if it is a dynamic key in flavor of another variable, use the brace notation

```
${bean.map[key]}
```

this is also useful if the hardcoded key itself contains one or more periods

```
${bean.map['key.with.periods']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is something similar to this possible with Struts 1.x tags ?

Comment: I know, this question is over 6 years old and I know you shouldn't be using struts 1 anymore, but in case anyone else is looking for this, the following worked for me: `<bean:write name="bean" property="map.key" />`